# Conditional filter in SELECT to avoid JOIN

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I'm wondering if there's an optimized, more readable way of doing the following in BigQuery:

```sql
select
  coalesce(a.item, b.item) as item,
  a.cost,
  b.flag_true_cost,
from
(
  select
  item,
  sum(cost) as cost,
  from test.t1
  group by item
) a
full join
(
  select
  item,
  sum(cost) as flag_true_cost
  from test.t1
  where flag = true
  group by item
) b
on a.item = b.item;
```

Output:

```
item    cost    flag_true_cost
pumpkin 3.5     3.5
apple   1.4     1.4
kale    20.3    2.3
```

Here is some pseudo-code of what I had in mind

```sql
select
item,
sum(cost) as cost,
if(flag=true, sum(cost)) as flag_true_cost
from test.t1
group by item;
```

Here is the sample data

```sql
create table test.t1 (item string, flag bool, cost numeric);

insert into test.t1 values
  ('kale', true, 2.3),
  ('kale', false, 18),
  ('apple', true, 1.4),
  ('pumpkin', true, 3.5)
;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here is some pseudo-code of what I had in mind

You are almost there. Just move the conditional *within* the aggregate function:

```
select item, sum(cost) as cost,
    sum(if(flag=true, cost, 0)) as flag_true_cost
from ayima-ad-hoc.test.t1
group by item;
```

Comment: I might also add a corresponding COUNT(*) for both all sum() vs sum( if()) so user knows that all costs were 30 entries, but of them, only 6 were true costs.  Dont know if that would help in their analysis of which costs were still pending vs projected.

Comment: @DRapp... in which case we could use [`countif` if BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#countif)